# how to form a DELETE REST URL for multiple items with angular ngresource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

suppose my curl url for DELETE request looks like

```
website.com/res/resource_name?myid=(1,2,3,4)
```

How should I create an angular resource wherein I simply pass an array of IDs and get this rest URL?

**note:**

I am using restSQL, this is an example for deleting a single item
http://restsql.org/doc/ref/ResDeleteQuery.html

I can delete a single item, but I want to delete multiple at the same time. The above rest URL works for me via curl request.

Comment: restangular customDELETE can do that

Answer (score 1):

This is not how REST works. One of the key principles of REST is that every resource has a unique URL. It implies you must perform a delete request for each resource. It's a drawback in this case, as it multiplies requests. But it allows caching response. And you read data much more frequently than you delete them ;)